# Thunderbird erases first part of email address when "@" is typed

Tags: email, thunderbird

When I attempt to type in an email address in the "To:" field in Thunderbird, the program erases the first part of the email address when "@" is typed. For instance, if I want to type in "person@examples.org", I write "person" and when I then press "@" I experience that "person" gets deleted.

I do not recall seeing that behavior before and I do not think I have changed any configurations. The Thunderbird version is 68.2.2.

I can write "@example.org" HOME "person" to get "person@example.org".

Comment: I also observed this behaviour on Firefox...

Comment: Interestingly enough, I have exactly the same version (and Ubuntu 19.10), but I do NOT have this problem. Could it be caused by some extension?

Comment: Same version, same Ubuntu (though with KDE), not reproducible.

Comment: Currently, I do not experience the problem. I suppose it may be a temporary state in Gnome or Thunderbird of some sort. I did not test if the problem appeared in Firefox.